# storybook fails to start after upgrade angular

Tags: node.js, angular, storybook

After I upgraded angular from 12 to 14 I have a problem with start storybook app.
There are some problems on run:

```
WARN   Failed to load preset: "C:\\Users\\a.shakirov\\project\\src\\front\\project-ui-kit\\node_modules\\@storybook\\angular\\dist\\ts3.9\\server\\framework-preset-angular-ivy.js"
ERR! Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\a.shakirov\project\src\front\project-ui-kit\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\ngcc\index.js
ERR! require() of ES modules is not supported.
ERR! require() of C:\Users\a.shakirov\project\src\front\project-ui-kit\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\ngcc\index.js from C:\Users\a.shakirov\project\src\front\project-ui-kit\node_modules\@storybook\angula
r\dist\ts3.9\server\framework-preset-angular-ivy.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
ERR! Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\a.shakirov\project\src\front\project-ui-kit\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\package.json.
```

and

```
ERR! => Could not get angular cli webpack config
ERR! Error: Missing required options in project target. Check "tsConfig, assets, 
optimization"
ERR!     at C:\Users\a.shakirov\project\src\front\project-ui-kit\node_modules\@storybook\angular\dist\ts3.9\server\angular-devkit-build-webpack.js:133:27
```

I haven't got any ideas how to fix them

Storybook version is 6.3.12

Node version is 14.17.6

Angular version is 14

Answer (score 0):

it seems Angular 14 is only supported from storybook version `7.0.0-alpha.0` so you would probably want to use test version in your project, untill the actual 7+ version is released

```
npm i --save-dev @storybook/angular@7.0.0-alpha.34
```

Comment: Any sources to say that Angular 14 is not supported by Storybook < 7?

Comment: storybook repository -> package.json doesn't list angular 14 as a supported one, that is the main reason